# "off-topic" flag was declined, but post was migrated anyway?

Tags: discussion, flagging

I recently flagged a post as "off-topic and unrelated to academia". The flag was declined. The post in question was migrated to another SE site, though, indicating that it was in fact off-topic and unrelated to academia.

So why was my flag declined, if I seemed to have been right in my judgement?

Comment: Bear in mind also that the community generally moderates itself. Most posts that are "off-topic and unrelated to academia" are handled by users with enough rep casting close votes without diamond moderators ever needing to get involved.